# Chapter number is not showing in elegantbook class for Bengali

Tags: fonts, numbering, chapters, fontspec, polyglossia

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{elegantbook}

%--------------------------------------------------
%Bengali Font in Document
%--------------------------------------------------

% For a bilingual document
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX, Scale=MatchUppercase}
% Times New Roman used for English
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}

% Bengali
\newfontfamily\bengalifont{Kalpurush}[
  Script=Bengali,
  Language=Bengali,
  AutoFakeBold = 0.2,
  AutoFakeSlant = 0.15  ]



%End--------------------------------------------

\title{শর্টকাট সূত্র ভান্ডার}
\subtitle{Subtitle here}

\author{Author Name}
\institute{Institute here}
\date{February 10, 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Fist Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\end{document}
```

Chapter number is not showing when compile with XeLaTex for Bengali. Here is the output:

[image]

I would like to get like below:
[image]

---

**Edit**
The problem does not seem to be related to Bengali specifically, but `polyglossia` and/or `elegantbook` in general.
It can be reproduced using

```
\documentclass{elegantbook}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Fist Chapter}
\end{document}
```

Commenting `\usepackage{polyglossia}` makes the number appear.

Comment: @schoekling I need to use Bengali. When I use \setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}

% Bengali
\newfontfamily\bengalifont{Kalpurush}[
  Script=Bengali,
  Language=Bengali,
  AutoFakeBold = 0.2,
  AutoFakeSlant = 0.15  ]  ,  chapter number is not appearing

Comment: I am not saying you shouldn't use it. But Bengali is not the root of the problem, so it's easier to look for the problem without it

Comment: `book` class shows chapter number with `polyglossia` for both english and bengali. `elegantbook` class is resetting things. It is loading many, many packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is unrelated to the Bengali language specifically.  The problem here is that your documentclass redefines the `\chaptername` macro to include the chapter number, and then `polyglossia` overrides `\chaptername` with a localized string that does not include the chapter number.

The fix is to redefine the formatting of the chapter style to print the chapter number separately from the caption.  I left the appendixes as A, B, C, etc.

```
\documentclass[11pt, titlestyle=hang]{elegantbook}
\tracinglostchars=2

%--------------------------------------------------
%Bengali Font in Document
%--------------------------------------------------
% For a bilingual document
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX, Scale=MatchUppercase}
% Times New Roman used for English
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[NFSSFamily=ntxtlf]
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}

% Bengali
\newfontfamily\bengalifont{Kalpurush}[
  Script=Bengali,
  Language=Bengali,
  AutoFakeBold = 0.2,
  AutoFakeSlant = 0.15,
  Scale=MatchUppercase  ]

\titleformat{\chapter}[\style]%
  {\bfseries}%
  {\filcenter\LARGE\enspace\bfseries{\color{structurecolor}\IfAppendix{\appendixname~\thechapter}{\chaptername~\arabic{chapter}}\enspace}}%
  {1pt}%
  {\bfseries\color{structurecolor}\LARGE\filcenter}[]


%End--------------------------------------------

\title{শর্টকাট সূত্র ভান্ডার}
\subtitle{Subtitle here}

\author{Author Name}
\institute{Institute here}
\date{February 10, 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\chapter{Second Chapter}

\appendix
\chapter{An Appendix}
\end{document}
```

Compile twice in XeTeX for everything to work.

This makes two fixes to how the fonts are loaded.  The `elegantbook` class is coded to use a `newtxtlf` font family, which breaks in `fontspec`, so you have to declare that an alias for Times New Roman with `NFSSFamily=newtxtlf`.  The other fonts in the document should be scaled to match the uppercase height.